# How to create FeatureLayer without Legend in Table Of Contents (TOC) using ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-engine, feature-layer

So what I am trying to accomplish is having a IGroupLayer that contains an IFeatureLayer and in the table of contents (TOC) there would be no + next to the feature layer (i.e. there is no legend). So far what I tried to do is this, which is not working:

```
ILegendInfo legendInfo = geoFeatureLayer.Renderer as ILegendInfo;
ILegendGroup legendGroup = legendInfo.get_LegendGroup(0);
legendGroup.Visible = false;
```

Comment: What happens if you call legendGroup.ClearClasses()?

Comment: The legend is removed, but so are the feature (i.e. the lines/polygons).